# How to detect and handle timeout in F.Promise.get(timeout)

Tags: java, asynchronous, exception, playframework-2.0

When I'm executing a call to `F.Promise.get(timeout)` I would expect a timeout exception.

Unfortunately the following snippet does not compile as `TimeoutException` is never actually thrown as it is a checked Exception.

```
final Promise<WSResponse> routeRequest = WS.url(baseRoute)…;
try {
    return routeRequest.get(10000);
} catch (final TimeoutException ex) {
    // log something
    return DEFAULT;
}
```

Which timeout exception is actually thrown by `F.Promise.get(timeout)`? (the documentation does not state any)

How to catch or deal with it?

Comment: Catch `Throwable` and see what you get?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried catching Throwable? See italics below (from the [Play Framework documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.0/api/java/play/libs/F.Promise.html#get(long))):

> **public A get(long timeout)**
>
> Awaits for the promise to get the result.
>
> **Parameters:** timeout - A user defined timeout in milliseconds
>
> **Returns:** The promised result
>
> ***Throws:*** java.lang.Throwable - if the calculation providing the promise threw an exception